# Content is not allowed in prolog

Tags: php, xml, vxml

Estou com um problema que é o seguinte. Eu tenho um host que lê um arquivo vxml.
Porém, se eu peço para ele ler um arquivo vxml, funciona.
Mas quando eu gero o conteúdo via PHP ele dá o erro do título

> Content is not allowed in prolog

```
<?php
    header('Content-type: application/xml');
    echo '<?xml version="1.0"?>';
?>

<vxml version="2.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/vxml">
    <form id="form_Main">
        <var name="callerID" expr="session.callerid" />

        <field name="digit1" type="digits?length=2">
            <prompt bargein="true">Lets add two digit values together</prompt>
            <prompt>Please speak, or key in any two digit value</prompt>

            <filled>
                <log expr="'**** FILLED ******'" />
                <log expr="'**** digit1 =' + digit1 + ' ***'" />
            </filled>
        </field>
        <field name="digit2" type="digits?length=2">
            <prompt bargein="false">Great.</prompt>
            <prompt>Now speak, or key in the second two digit value</prompt>
            <filled>
                <log expr="' *** FILLED *********'" />
                <log expr="' *** digit2 =' + digit2 + ' ***'" />
                <submit next="AddDigits.php" method="get" namelist="digit1 digit2 callerID" />
            </filled>
        </field>
    </form>
</vxml>
```

O erro é na linha 3 `echo '<?xml version="1.0"?>';`
Eu sei que são os apóstrofos. Porém, se eu rodo no meu servidor PHP funciona, mas quando faço a máquina ler dá o erro.

Alguem já passou por isso?

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que falta o `encoding`, faça isto:

```
<?php
    header('Content-type: application/xml');
    echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>';
?>

<vxml version="2.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/vxml">
```

Também é necessário verificar se não há nada antes do `header`. No exemplo que você enviou não tem nenhum problema de caractere, claro isto se for o exemplo completo, abra o XML gerado abre diretamente no browser.